# Как убрать отступы от краев экрана кустарного UI в зависимости от разрешения?

Tags: java, алгоритм, разработка-игр, gui

Я пишу игру на Java, (с использованием движка [Slick2D](http://slick.ninjacave.com/) и библиотеки [MarteEngine](https://github.com/Gornova/MarteEngine), если это важно), и реализуя свой UI столкнулся с появлением отступов **слева** и **сверху**, если персонаж подходит слишком близко к этим краям экрана. Справа и снизу никаких проблем. Методом научного тыка выяснилось, что размеры отступов зависят от разрешения окна, и нашлись их приблизительные значения, но это не выход..
Что удалось выяснить:

- для `800х600` это 100 по вертикали, и 0 по горизонтали
- для `640х480` это 18 по горизонтали и 60 по вертикали

[Полный код проекта](https://github.com/Maggistrator/The_Story), если нужно.
*(архив будет сравнительно толстый из-за ресурсов)*
Исходный код класса:

```
package system;
import org.newdawn.slick.Color;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;     
import core.MyWorld;
import entities.TwilightSparkle;

public class WorldUI {

//мир, которому принадлежит интерфейс
MyWorld parent;


//нижняя панель
protected Image bottomBar;
protected Image battleBottomBar;

//верхняя панель
protected Image topBar;

//полосы жизни, и очков магии
protected Image HP;
protected Image IP;

//относительные координаты интерфейса
float interfaceX = 0;
float interfaceY = 0;

private boolean debug;

public WorldUI(MyWorld parent, GameContainer container) {
    this.parent = parent;
    interfaceX = (container.getWidth() - parent.twilie.hitboxWidth)/2;
    interfaceY = (container.getHeight() - parent.twilie.hitboxHeight)/2;
}

public void init() throws SlickException {
    topBar = new Image("textures/topBar.png");
    bottomBar = new Image("textures/Interface2.png");
    battleBottomBar = new Image("textures/Interface3.png");
    HP = new Image("textures/IP.png");
    IP = new Image("textures/HP.png");
}

public void draw(Graphics g) {
    //жизнь и мана
    HP.draw(interfaceX+100, interfaceY+parent.container.getHeight()-90);//520  
    IP.draw(interfaceX+100, interfaceY+parent.container.getHeight()-50);//560  

    //верхняя и нижняя рамка интерфейса
    topBar.draw(interfaceX, interfaceY);   
    bottomBar.draw(interfaceX, interfaceY+parent.container.getHeight()-128);

    //Отладка
    if(debug) {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawString(this.toString(), interfaceX+parent.container.getWidth()/2, interfaceY+20);
    }
}

public void update() {
    System.out.println("--- updates! ---");
    //полезные переменные для сокращения кода
    TwilightSparkle pony = MyWorld.twilie;

    int worldWidth = parent.width;
    int worldHeight = parent.height;
    int screenWidth = parent.container.getWidth();
    int screenHeight = parent.container.getHeight();       
    int halfOfScreenWidth = (screenWidth - pony.hitboxWidth)/2;
    int halfOfScreenHeight = (screenHeight - pony.hitboxHeight)/2;

    //если мы не достигли границ экрана, то координаты интерфейса следуют за персонажем     
    float halfOfPonyPositionX = pony.x - halfOfScreenWidth;
    float halfOfPonyPositionY = pony.y - halfOfScreenHeight;

    if(halfOfPonyPositionX  +100/* + 18*/ > halfOfScreenWidth && halfOfPonyPositionX + screenWidth < worldWidth) {
        interfaceX = halfOfPonyPositionX;
        System.out.println("upd X");
        System.out.println("interfaceX = halfOfPonyPositionX = "+(interfaceX));
    }

    if(halfOfPonyPositionY > halfOfScreenHeight /*+ 60*/ && halfOfPonyPositionY + screenHeight < worldHeight) {
         interfaceY = halfOfPonyPositionY;
            System.out.println("upd Y");
            System.out.println("interfaceY = halfOfPonyPositionY = "+(interfaceY));
    }

}

public void debug(boolean debug) {
    this.debug = debug;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder("--- Interface Log ---");
    log.append("\n"+"interfaceX = " + interfaceX);
    log.append("\n"+"interfaceY = " + interfaceY);

    log.append("\n"+"halfOfScreenWidth = " + parent.container.getWidth()/2);
    log.append("\n"+"halfOfScreenHeight = " + parent.container.getHeight()/2);

    log.append("\n"+"Twi X = " + parent.twilie.x);
    log.append("\n"+"Twi Y = " + parent.twilie.y);

    log.append( "\n"+"worldWidth = " + parent.width);
    log.append( "\n"+"screenHeight = " + parent.height);

    return log.toString();
}

}
```

Вопрос, как убрать эти отступы?

Comment: @Kromster скорее всего, вот - "столкнулся с появлением отступов слева и сверху, если персонаж подходит слишком близко к этим краям экрана"

Comment: @Kromster суть вопроса в том, как их убрать (Хардкодить приблизительные значения отступов через case - это крайний вариант)